# Does $\lim a_n$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ be two positive real sequences.

> If $0\leq a_n \leq b_n$ and $\lim b_n$ exists. Is $\lim a_n$ exists?

I ask this question because now I'm reading a paper and I think the authors used the above properties, but I think it's not in general true.

[image]

Comment: It is true if $(a_n)$ is monotonous from a certain $n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course it is not true in general. Take $a_n=1+(-1)^n$ and $b_n=2$. Then your conditions are satisfied, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think there is  a wrong in the paper?

Comment: @Student There would be an error if the conclusion was that $\lim_{s\to\infty}\bigl\|M_T^s(I)\bigr\|^{1/s}$ exists, but that's not the conclusion that the author reaches.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that you can say is probably that $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n\leq \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} b_n$.